# <li> item in navigation bar is extending too far to right side on smaller devices in dev tools

Tags: css, layout, html-lists, navbar, viewport

I cant figure out how to keep the unordered list items from extending too far to the right in the viewport. I have tried using **width: 100%;** for a responsive layout but with no luck. I'm starting to think it has to do with the **display:** selector.

The layout is fine 769px and above.

[navigation bar extending too far to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCUe7.jpg)

```
.drop-navbar {
    background: rgb(49, 1, 70);
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid white 2px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.drop-navbar ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: aliceblue;
}
.drop-navbar ul li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.drop-navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
}
.drop-link {
    display: none;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(49, 1, 70);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(153, 0, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link ul li {
    width: 125px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(153, 0, 255);
}
```

```
<div class="site-container">
    <nav class="drop-navbar">
        <img class="navbarbg" src="resources/css/jessiemeesphotos/navbarbg.png">
        <strong>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">For Sale</a>
                    <div class="drop-link">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="for_sale.html">Earrings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="for_sale.html">Necklaces</a></li>
                            <li><a href="for_sale.html">Rings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="for_sale.html">Bracelets</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </strong>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: please share a snippet or sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding from your `<ul>` element to center the items.

```
.drop-navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @ Dan Mullin. I've tried removing the padding but when I do, of course, all the list items smash together and when I try to separate them it sends them out of view again. Should I use a container around the entire <nav> element and try some different positioning? I tried linking normalize.css to the page to help out but for some reason it won't link and I get an error message in the console. Thanks again for your response. Sorry if my explanation is difficult to understand.

Comment: Edit: Modified answer to include spacing of li items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the padding in this part and set it to 0.

```
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link ul {
 display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And change the margin to -55px in this part.

```
.drop-navbar ul li:hover .drop-link {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(49, 1, 70);
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -55px;
}
```

It should center the drop-link where you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, @Vukasin! That worked well with the .droplink class. Appreciate your help.